# Compiz error with 12.04 on boot: can't see any desktop icons or taskbar

Tags: 12.04, boot, compiz, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.

When I ran the Live CD, everything worked fine but when I installed it I get a desktop orange/purple screen but nothing else on it.

I first get a screen saying that my monitor is out of range which didn't happen with the trial version.

Something about **compiz** not loading

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the exact error messages -- both for the *monitor out of range* and *compiz not loading*

Answer (score 0):

Press the left shift key early in the boot process to access the Grub2 menu.
I believe you can find what you're looking for there. Load recovery Mode, and check your graphics settings.  Make sure the right VGA driver is loaded, and also check your resolution, make sure that your monitor can handle it.

Comment: What is he/she looking for? You really need to elaborate in this answer, it is too generic.